# Java - SimpleDateFormat as a data type?

Tags: java, class, simpledateformat

I have an assignment I am working on for my class. In this assignment, I am asked to create the constructor and the get/set methods. I have done all of that EXCEPT in one of the classes, there are several attributes is listed which use "SimpleDateFormat" as a data type. In all my research, I've found SimpleDateFormat as a method, but not as a data type in itself (such as String or Boolean) and I don't see where it's been set up anywhere else except to import  "import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;" into the class file. I cannot find anywhere that there's any kind of default format for this as a data type - I am brand new to Java of course so I amy be overlooking it, or missing something completely - but it's not being covered in my text in any way so I'm hoping you wonderful gurus can lend a hand and help point me in the right direction.

Here is the section of the attributes in the class file I was given for this assignment:

```
private SimpleDateFormat acquisitionDate;
private SimpleDateFormat statusDate;
private String acquisitionSource;
private Boolean reserved;

private String trainingLocation;
private SimpleDateFormat trainingStart;
private SimpleDateFormat trainingEnd;
private String trainingStatus;
```

Any help/insight is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Here is the javadocs https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Where have you found that `SimpleDateFormat` is a method, not a type?

Comment: @Tom I probably have the verbiage wrong but I was looking it up here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html and it returns that it's a method that I would have to create each date object ... it seems far more convoluted than the assignment and the level of the class... I will reach out to my instructor for further clarify I just wanted to get validation that I wasn't overlooking something simple in just assigning a formatted date of acquisitionDate = "12/1/19" or "Dec 1 19" or something to this effect in my constructor assignments. Thank you.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `DateTimeFormatter` and other classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). You can tell your instructor the same if relevant.

Comment: Technically the outdated `SimpleDateFormat` was a *class* just like `String` and `Boolean` are classes. And therefore also a type. It had got methods just like they have got methods. The difference is that it was a *utility class*, what Larman calls a [pure fabrication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRASP_(object-oriented_design)#Pure_fabrication), so not useful for holding domain data. Only in this way you are correct in not regarding it as a *data* type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change SimpleDateFormat  to Date or String.
SimpleDateFormat  is just a way to convert String to Date and vice versa with wanted format.
it shouldn't be treated as date type.

Comment: This is good. Additionally, when you need to store a "date" and do no date manipulation stuff, it is better to store these dates as `String`. When date manipulation is needed, it is better to use `LocalDate`, or `LocalDateTime`, or any other data types in `java.time` package. These new classes offers simplier method when manipulating date vs `java.util.Date` class.